# getting [object, object] when dropdown value is selected - instead of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coming to a problem where I have a dropdown with jsf tags and when I select a dropdown value - it shows `[Object, object]`.  I try to convert from object to string using `JSON.stringify(data);` but it did not quite work. Can anyone help me solve this issue. I have a search input where the values show a html table - I want to do the same with my dropdown. thanks for the help.

**Here is my code**

```js
$('#sJobClass').on('change', function() {
  var jobClassCd = $(this).val(); 
  if (jobClassCd !== 0) {
    $.post('http://localhost:8080/myApp/JobSearchItem.xhtml',
           $('#searchForms').serialize(),
           function(data) {
             $('#results').append(data + '<br/><br/>');
             // $('#results').append($(text).find('table'));
             console.log(data);
             JSON.stringify(data);
           });

    $("#clearone").show();
  }
});
```

**HTML with JSF tags**

```html
<select class="selectMenuSize" id="sJobClass" name="sJobClass">
  <option value="">choose</option>
  <c:forEach items="#{myBean.jobSearchItems}" var="searchItem">
    <option value="#{searchItem.getSearchValue()}" id="searchInputField"
            name="searchInput">#{searchItem.toString()}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

**Data**

```
{
  id: "11111",
  label: "PROGRAMMER (1111) ",
  value: "11111"
}
```

Comment: `data` is an object. When an object is added to a string, that object's `toString` method is called. `toString` returns `"[object Object]"` for objects.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` works, but you'll have to use its return value: `$('#results').append(JSON.stringify(data) + '<br/><br/>');`

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be calling `JSON.stringify(data)` (which is correct) but opting to ignore the result and instead use the raw value of `data` (which is not).

Try this as your callback function:

```js
function(data) {
   $('#results').append(JSON.stringify(data) + '<br/><br/>');
});
```

Comment: thanks. But, if I want to show my table. Can i do something like this: `    `$('#results').append(JSON.stringify(data).find('table'));` ?

Comment: Where are you finding `table` in the sample data you’ve provided? **EDIT**: if you mean `label`, you should not be using `stringify` here. Since `data` is  already a plain JS object, just use `data.label`.

Comment: well, I have a html table shown `<table class="table">` that I need it to show instead of the json results.

Comment: There is no magical function you can call to convert a JS object into a table. You'll need to write this function yourself. Note that you can use `data.label` etc to access the parts of your data, and see what you can come up with. If you have trouble, edit your question with your progress

Answer (score 0):

you append all the return object and they have multiple attribution witch one you need to display in results ?

```js
$('#results').append(data.label + '<br/><br/>');

$('#results').append(data.id + data.label + '<br/><br/>');
```

Comment: something like this: `$('#results').append($(data).find('table'));`